# Does Vim compile user-defined functions?

Tags: vimscript, functions

If I define a function in my vimrc (or in a plugin), Vim will load it and I can use it. But what's happening under the hood after my vimscript is parsed?

Is it transcoded down to C and compiled?

Is it put on the heap at runtime and referenced through a function pointer?

Comment: Vimscript is nothing more than series of ex commands so your functions are interpreted just like any ex commands. No compilation or transcoding necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it transcoded down to C and compiled?

Vimscript is interpreted, and in fact you can do basically the same things in vimscript as you could at the `:` command (and the other way around), plus or minus some bar and escape characters to make things sane.

The evaluation code is mainly located in [`eval.c`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/eval.c), which you can browse if you are brave.

> Is it put on the heap at runtime and referenced through a function
>   pointer?

While a built-in function *is* ultimately a function pointer to the C implementation, a user function is represented by a `ufunc_T` structure (trimmed of some stuff for brevity):

```
struct ufunc
{
    int      uf_varargs;
    int      uf_flags;
    int      uf_calls;
    garray_T uf_args;
    garray_T uf_lines;
    scid_T   uf_script_ID;
    int      uf_refcount;
    char_u   uf_name[1];
};
```

The function `call_user_func` is used to actually make the call to a user function. After doing a ton of setup to initialize arguments, variables, profiling information and state management, `call_user_func` does

```
do_cmdline(NULL, get_func_line, (void *)fc, DOCMD_NOWAIT|DOCMD_VERBOSE|DOCMD_REPEAT);
```

to execute each line of the function as a `:` command line (the implementation of `do_cmdline` in in [ex_docmd.c](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/fb1f62691eae7c79a28b3b17a60e72ce198c71a2/src/ex_docmd.c#L745)).

Comment: Sated my curiosity. Great answer!